# HTML5 drag and drop баг в chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-n-drop

Я обнаружил странное поведение перетаскиваемой картинки в Chrome, тогда как в FIREFOX все работает отлично. Дело в том что при использовании метода
`e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(e.target, e.target.width / 2, e.target.height / 2);`
в chrome захватывается не только картинка, а еще и задний фон. Посмотрите демонстрацию бага:

```js
const onDragStart = (e) => {
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
  e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(e.target, e.target.width / 2, e.target.height / 2);
};
    
    
const onDragLeave = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
};

const onDragOver = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
};


document.addEventListener("dragstart", onDragStart, false);
document.addEventListener("dragover", onDragOver, false);
document.addEventListener("dragleave", onDragLeave, false);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,0,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,255,255,1) 100%);
  padding: 10px;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" draggable="false">
  <img draggable="true" class="img" src="https://images.emojiterra.com/twitter/v12/512px/1f914.png"/>
</div>
```

**Как мне решить проблему?** В моем проекте метод `setDragImage` важен и без его использования решения я не рассматриваю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну прям багом это не назвать, особенность реализации =), помогает не брать изображения из DOM, а например создать новое при старте перетаскивания или заранее.

Однако это порождает другую проблему - хватается картинка оригинального размера, и если это критично то это обходить уже проблематично(при помощи канвы), но можно, если это интересно могу дополнить ответ.

Однако проще подобрать размеры заранее...

```js
img.addEventListener("dragstart", e => {
  let img = document.createElement('img')
  img.src = e.target.src
  e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, img.width / 2, img.height / 2);
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,0,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,255,255,1) 100%);
  padding: 10px;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img id="img" draggable="true" class="img" src="https://images.emojiterra.com/twitter/v12/512px/1f914.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ваш ответ. Заработало)

Comment: @RafaelShepard рад помочь